# MongoDB add to joining collection field from base one

Tags: mongodb, join, merge, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collections:

Games with schema:

```
 _id: ObjectId('gameId'),
 questions: [
   {
     position: 1,
     question_id: ObjectId('baz')
   },
   {
     position: 2,
     question_id: ObjectId('ban')
   },
 ]
```

Questions with schema:

```
 _id: ObjectId('baz'),
 text: 'FooBar'
```

And now I'd like to join questions to games with adding to each question record value of `question_position`.

So, I have query like this:

```
db.games.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'questions',       
        localField: 'questions.question_id',
        foreignField: '_id',       
        as: 'question_data',     
      },   
     }])
```

Which return me all required info, with correct join according to questions array,

```
 _id: ObjectId('gameId'),
 questions: [
   {
     position: 1,
     question_id: ObjectId('baz')
   },
   {
     position: 2,
     question_id: ObjectId('ban')
   }
 ],
 question_data: [
   {
     _id: ObjectId('baz'),
     text: 'FooBar',
   },
   {
     _id: ObjectId('ban'),
     text: 'FooBar2',
   }
 ]
```

but I'm totally can't figure out how to add into joined questions it's position according to game.
To look it like this:

```
 _id: ObjectId('gameId'),
 questions: [
   {
     position: 1,
     question_id: ObjectId('baz')
   },
   {
     position: 2,
     question_id: ObjectId('ban')
   }
 ],
 question_data: [
   {
     _id: ObjectId('baz'),
     text: 'FooBar',
     position: 1,
   },
   {
     _id: ObjectId('ban'),
     text: 'FooBar2',
     position: 2,
   }
 ]
```

I've tried with `$unwind` for question array in game collection, played a little with `$project` in `aggregation` but still no result.

**So**, my question is, how to add field from base collection to joined data from another collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `questions` array and then need to apply [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and finally use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to rollback again into the array.

```
db.games.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$questions" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "questions",
    "localField": "questions.question_id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "question_data"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$question_data" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "question_data.position": "$questions.position",
    "question_data.question_id": "$questions.question_id"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "questions": { "$push": "$questions" },
    "question_data": { "$push": "$question_data" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!